# How to create imbalace sample data with make_blobs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using make_blobs from sklearn package.

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
```

I want to create sample data with imbalance features. Example I want 400 of FeatureA and 50 of FeatureB.

ByDefault below code is generating both features in equal numbers:-

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=450, centers=2, cluster_std=[10.0, 2],random_state=22,n_features=2)
```

Following is the count plot created for the data generated from above code:-
[image]

Please suggest as how can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create 2 class of data with predetermined std and center one 400 and others be 50. I set "centers=None" .Am I right?  I use this code and it gives what you want. please refer to this link:
[sklearn.datasets.make_blobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=[400,50], centers=None, cluster_std=[10.0, 2],random_state=22,n_features=2)
print(y)
Zero0=np.where(y == 0)[0]
One1=np.where(y == 1)[0]
print(Zero0)
print(One1)
plt.scatter(X[Zero0,0],X[Zero0,1],color=['red'])
plt.scatter(X[One1,0],X[One1,1],color=['green'])
plt.show()
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting error. "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."

Comment: I don't set float64 or other data type for my code.